# Cannot read property 'toResolveHierarchy' of undefined

Tags: javascript, i18next

I call the `i18next` change Language function by passing the language code (en-UK) like that :

```
var changeLng = function (varLng) {  
  i18next.changeLanguage('en', (err, t) => {
    if (err) return console.log('something went wrong loading', err);
    t('applog'); // -> same as i18next.t
  });
};
```

I got the following issue :

```
VM4081 i18next.js:1912 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toResolveHierarchy' of undefined
    at setLng (VM4081 i18next.js:1912)
    at I18n.changeLanguage (VM4081 i18next.js:1927)
    at changeLng (VM4079 langUK.js:23)
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (VM4079 langUK.js:8)
```

I assume that Something going wrong when `i18next` tries to execute that :

```
_this4.languages = _this4.services.languageUtils.toResolveHierarchy(l);
```

But I can't see what's needed to properly execute this.
Thanks in advance for your support,
Jack

Answer (score 5):

Did you initialize `i18next` properly? This code works for me:

```js
i18next.init({
  lng: 'en',
  debug: true,
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: {
        "key": "hello world"
      }
    }
  }
}, function(err, t) {
  // initialized and ready to go!
  console.log("Ready to go!");
});

var changeLng = function(varLng) {
  i18next.changeLanguage('en', (err, t) => {
    if (err) return console.log('something went wrong loading', err);
    t('applog'); // -> same as i18next.t
  });
};

changeLng()
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/i18next/i18next.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:** [took this from the documentation](https://www.i18next.com/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is caused by a bad import of `i18next` or that it hasn't been inited, like "import i18n from 'i18next'".
Run the init function firstly, then you can run the changeLanguage.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply import your ./i18n.js and use the exported i18next instance:
import i18next from './i18n'
Import like this and use i18next on change language and .on function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).